# Import with dot name in python

Tags: python, import

How can I import a dotted name file in python?

I don't mean a relative path, but a filename starting or containing a dot `"."`

For example: `'.test.py'` is the filename.

`import .test` will search for a `test` package with a `py` module in a parent package.

Comment: Don’t name a module like that.

Comment: @poke agreed. Just wondering if it is possible

Comment: Btw. the general `import .test` already fails because `import something` will always make `something` available as a variable name; and `.test` is not a valid name.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The situation is tricky, because dots mean sub-package structure to Python. I recommend simply renaming your modules instead, if that's an option!

However, importing a source file directly is still possible:

#### Python 2

Using [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html):

```py
import imp
my_module = imp.load_source("my_module", ".test.py")
```

---

#### Python 3

The imp module was deprecated in favor of `importlib` and [has been removed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#imp) in Python 3.12. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly) is a Python 3 replacement:

```py
import importlib.util 
    
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
    name="my_module",  # note that ".test" is not a valid module name
    location="/path/to/.test.py",
)
my_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(my_module)
```

Comment: any advise about python3?

Comment: @variable Yes, see https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly

Comment: Really Python? 
Why not from ./my/class.utils.py import Utils