# PyTest fails to collect files numbered with a decimal point

Tags: python, pytest

I am working on a suite of python scripts that are used for testing hardware, and I have been tasked with making them compatible with PyTest. I'm running into an issue with our team's naming convention, where the tests are numbered "section.subsection" followed by the name: `1.12_example_name_test.py`. I get this error whenever I run py.test:

```
$ py.test 1.12_example_name_test.py

======== ERRORS =========
____ ERROR collecting 1.12_example_name_test.py _______
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
E   ImportError: No module named '1'
====== 1 error in 0.03 seconds ======
```

Is there a way to change PyTest's test discovery so it doesn't think that the decimal point is referring to a module? The test will run fine when I change the name to use an underscore instead of a point, but I would like to avoid changing the naming convention since there is a large git repository filled with these scripts, I don't want to lose the git history from each one.

Comment: Unless you are asking how to change these in Git, I don't think the Git tag is appropriate. I'm not going to edit it away myself yet, though.

Comment: Tag removed. I was thinking if I can't fix it by configuring PyTest I might have to settle for making changes that would affect Git instead, but that's a last resort and not really what the question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't name Python modules like that.  It is [actually possible to import them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27189110/674039), but your chances of getting pytest runner to be able to do that are approximately zero.

The right plan of action is convince your team that the team's naming convention is insane.  And avoid the leading digits, too.   Something like this is acceptable:

```
test_1_12_example_name.py
```