# How to import variables from one file into another

Tags: python, linux, variables, import, module

I'm trying to take a separate text file, with a list of defined variables, and import them into the main py file. Not trying any classes or functions, just predefined variables. I tried a number of different solutions but the syntax isn't working for all the different types.I'm working on a Linux device and .py is in the file name. I dont know if that's causing an issue or not so I renamed it and still is not working. Files are here.

```
list of variables:
    /home/example/file.module.py

actual code file to run:
    /home/example/filetorun.py

I've tried on filetorun:
    import file.module.py 
    import 'file.module.py'
    from file.module.py import *
    from 'file.module.py' import *
    import ./file.module.py
    import /home/example/file.module.py
    (renamed file to file.module) import /home/example/file.module

All these are not working, not sure if have to make a function to return all these values or what.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have a dot in the file name. Either change the name of the file and follow what I have posted below, or check out `importlib.util` from this post: [Import with dot name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189044/import-with-dot-name-in-python)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-import-variables-from-another-file-in-python/

Import the file (no need to specify Path if in same directory) and then use the file name pre-the variable.

```
# calval.py file where to import variables
# import swaps.py file from which variables 
# to be imported
# swaps.py and calval.py files should be in 
# same directory.
import swaps
  
# Import x and y variables using 
# file_name.variable_name notation
new_x = swaps.x
new_y = swaps.y
  
print("x value: ", new_x, "y value:", new_y)
  
# Similarly, import swapVal method from swaps file
x , y = swaps.swapVal(new_x,new_y)
  
print("x value: ", x, "y value:", y)
```

Comment: I renamed the file to creds and get the following error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'creds'

Comment: are you using 'import creds'?

Comment: You should not be using creds.py, only creds @Meme-ento

Comment: yup only import creds, get modulenotfounderror